# Servlet not sending attribute towards jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a servlet and I want to send data from it towards a jsp file:

```
        String errmsg = "Services not available!";
        request.setAttribute("errmsg",errmsg);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/web/csrCustomerLists/custListDetails.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Sadly, the attribute is not set in the file and I am receiving null in jsp. I have tried two ways:

```
        <div> <%  String message = (String) request.getAttribute("errmsg");</div>
                                        out.println("Servlet communicated message to JSP: "+ message);%>
        <div>Try no:2<c:out value="${errmsg}"/></div>
```

I inspected with firebug and I am getting this:

```
Servlet communicated message to JSP: null
```

Thanks in advance.

Update: 
I managed to get an error after all:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Implicit variable [javax.portlet.response] not available in the request context.

Comment: What URL you used to see the value? Is it servlet URL or JSP URL?

Comment: I used the JSP URL to see the value

Comment: Well, is there any filters which might replace/wrap the original request? you can debug it and log the hash code of the request instance for the two places, and check whether they refer to the same object.

Comment: @RazvanN, You should use servlet URL. Look at my answer.

Comment: If you downvote, please comment why, I am interested in getting an answer here, though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try in another way

by keeping those values in session

Syntax `session.setAttribute("errmsg",errmsg);` and to retrieve `session.getAttribute("errmsg");`

In servlet do like this

```
HttpSession session =request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("errmsg",errmsg);
```

and in jsp page simply do `session.getAttribute("errmsg");`

Comment: You refer to this syntax? `request.getSession().setAttribute`

Comment: I updated with an error message, that links to the line with getRequestDispatcher

Comment: @RazvanN I told you to store in the session but you have not

Comment: So i tried again, as you said in the answer, it comes null in jsp at session.getAttribute("errmsg");

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42941/discussion-between-jquerylearner-and-razvan-n)

Comment: I mananged to find a solution with your idea. Thanks a lot @JqueryLearner

Comment: @RazvanN you are welcome.Always ready to help.fell free to ask if you have any other queries

Answer (score 0):

You get `null` because you used JSP page URL, where value is not still set. You should use servlet URL to see the value. Because, value should be passed from `Servlet` to JSP. So your URL should be like:

```
  http://localhost:8080/AppName/ServletURL // After hit this URL
          |                                 // value will be forwarded to JSP
          |
          |
 http://localhost:8080/AppName/MyJSP.jsp // this will be invoked with
                                         // requestDispatcher.forward
```

Comment: @RazvanN, After hit the Servlet URL, it will be forwarded to JSP page with value.

Comment: I made the form call the servlet with action, it does the right thing, but still not displaying the value...

Comment: @RazvanN, Is your page content displaying? Another thing, you can't directly access JSP page from WEB-INF directory, Try to keep JSP page outside of this directory.

Comment: Everything is displaying.I can't put the jsp page somehwhere else, there is a connection between them..

Comment: If you still got problem, than go through this basic tutorial. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaeo.html

Answer (score 0):

looks like the issue is here

```
<div> <%  String message = (String) request.getAttribute("errmsg");</div>
```

You have to close the scriptlet properly. Try this:

```
<div> 
<%  String message = (String) request.getAttribute("errmsg");
out.println("Servlet communicated message to JSP: "+ message);%>
</div>
```